# cast operator function compiles fine in g++ but not in other compilers. Why?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, g++, language-lawyer, clang++

Consider following program:

```
struct S {
    using T = float;
    operator T() { return 9.9f; }
};
int main() {
    S m;
    S::T t = m;
    t = m.operator T(); // Is this correct ?
}
```

The program compiles fine in g++ ( See live demo [***here***](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f94bed9444a2dd46) )

But it fails in compilation in clang++, MSVC++ & Intel C++ compiler

clang++ gives following errors ( See live demo [***here***](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/48b2e0746a27f9e3) )

```
main.cpp:8:20: error: unknown type name 'T'; did you mean 'S::T'?
    t = m.operator T(); // Is this correct ?
                   ^
                   S::T
main.cpp:2:11: note: 'S::T' declared here
    using T = float;
```

MSVC++ gives following errors ( See live demo [***here***](http://rextester.com/FSZ10044) )

```
source_file.cpp(8): error C2833: 'operator T' is not a recognized operator or type
source_file.cpp(8): error C2059: syntax error: 'newline'
```

Intel C++ Compiler also rejects this code ( See live demo [***here***](https://godbolt.org/g/8b5F4z) )

**So, the question is which compiler is right here ? Is g++  incorrect here or other 3 compilers are incorrect here ? What C++ standard says about this ?**

Comment: Wow, very nice question!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[[basic.lookup.classref]/7](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.lookup.classref#7):

> If the *id-expression* is a *conversion-function-id*, **its *conversion-type-id* is first looked up in the class of the object expression and the name, if found, is used**. Otherwise it is looked up in the context of the entire
>   *postfix-expression*. In each of these lookups, only names that denote types or templates whose specializations are types are considered. [ *Example*:
>
> ```
> struct A { };
> namespace N {
>   struct A {
>     void g() { }
>     template <class T> operator T();
>   };
> }
>
> int main() {
>   N::A a;
>   a.operator A();  // calls N::A::operator N::A
> }
> ```
>
> — *end example*]

This indicates that the example could be fine, although in the above example, `A` has previously been declared as a type name, visible to `main`.

This was discussed in [core issue 156](http://wg21.link/cwg156), filed all the way back in 1999:

> How about:
>
> ```
> struct A { typedef int T; operator T(); };
> struct B : A { operator T(); } b;
> void foo() {
>   b.A::operator T(); // 2) error T is not found in the context
>                      // of the postfix-expression?
> }
> ```
>
> Is this interpretation correct? Or was the intent for this to be an
>   error only if `T` was found in both scopes and referred to different
>   entities?
>
> **Erwin Unruh: The intent was that you look in both contexts. If you find it only once, that's the symbol.** If you find it in both, both symbols must be "the same" in some respect. (If you don't find it, its an error).

So I'd say that Clang is wrong: the intent, as expressed in the wording to some extent, is that we find `T`, even if only in the class.

Comment: A surprising gotcha!

Comment: You should also say ICC & MSVC++ are also wrong. only g++ is right !!!

Comment: @Destructor Yes, but Clang in particular is interesting, because it is usually right. In the last 10 or 20 language-lawyer questions in which Clang and GCC differed in behavior, Clang was correct.

Comment: @Columbo: I am not very good in understanding standerdese. Will you please explain in simpler words what is id expression ?

Comment: @Destructor An expression that denotes an entity (more informally, an entity's "name").

Comment: Knew this looked familiar. [llvm bug 27807](https://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=27807)

Comment: @Barry Stop preempting me in the past :*